# Remove the file inside CUBA Platform's FileUpload component

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a modal with a FileUpload component inside it. When a user uploads something, the file is seen inside the upload component. But when the modal is closed and opened again user still can see the link to the file again. How to remove it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share screen descriptor code of the modal dialog.